# How to increase memcached item max size in docker

Tags: docker, memcached

When using memcached with docker, how can I set the max item size?

I know the following can be done e.g. -m 64 to set the storage limit:

```
docker run --name my-memcache -d memcached memcached -m 64
```

I also know that in a Linux box the following can be done to set item max size limit:

```
MAXITEMSIZE=5m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [entry point](https://github.com/docker-library/memcached/blob/39fb13c73f938d2eb12633be4dea548f4ea2971f/debian/docker-entrypoint.sh) script in the memcached image will pass on command line options

```
docker run --name my-memcache -d memcached -I 10m
```

If you want to make the option default to something and be configured by the `MAXITEMSIZE` environment variable you could create an image `FROM memcached` and copy a new entry point script in.

```
FROM memcached
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

The script needs to cater for when a user doesn't run `memcached` and when they specify the `-I` option manually.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ue

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
  set -- memcached "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = "memcached" ]; then
  shift
  MAXITEMSIZE=${MAXITEMSIZE:-1m}
  set -- memcached -I "$MAXITEMSIZE" "$@" 
fi

exec "$@"
```